# Google maps gets GPS fix faster than LocationManager! WHY?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

**Setup**

Mobile set to GPS only. Network NOT enabled.

Implemented `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates` to get a location fix. After long period of inactivity (like overnight) it takes the LocationManager more than 3 minutes to get a fix. Subsequent updates are reasonably fast (like 5-10 seconds).

If I instead open up Google Maps first, it gets my location over GPS in under 1 minute.

Why is Google Maps so much faster when starting up GPS cold?

Please note:

I know I can speed up the location fix, if I enable NETWORK_PROVIDER. But that is not the question here. The question here: What is GMaps doing different given using only GPS?

Comment: "What is GMaps doing different given using only GPS?" -- Google Maps is a proprietary application. While we have been told that it uses the Play Services SDK's location APIs, it might not. The only way you will be able to find out how Google Maps is implemented is to get a job at Google and ask them.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is here!!

Google and others like Apple and Skyhook build a Database which links WLAN BSSIDs to a geographic location. A BSSID is like the MAC Address of a access point that gets broadcasted by that access point. It is therefore "public viewable" if the BSSID broadcast is enabled, which is the default for most access points. The BSSID operates on a lower layer as the IP stack, you don't even have to be connected to an access point to receive these broadcasts.

Every time you run Google Maps or Navigation with enabled GPS and WiFi and if your device is able to get a good GPS fix, the current visible WLAN networks and your current location (the GPS fix) are uploaded to Google to build and update the database. This technique is sometimes called crowdsourcing. Every Android device acts therefore as data collector.

Since most access points are static in their position and only cover a small area - the coverage radius is approximately 100m - they are ideal anchors for a good location fix without GPS.